# Hide div containing a URL with css in @media

Tags: html, css

I can't find the correct css selector to hide this div for mobile screens:

```
<div w3-include-left-html="borders/border-left.html"></div>
```

I have tried many selectors, but none work. Example:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
div.borders/border-left.html {
display: none;
    }
}
```

The div code with URL in it works as it should, but the selector to hide the div on mobile screens eludes me.

I have not found anything on StackOverflow that provides a css selector for div code with a URL in it, like above.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

NOTE: The full code including the div file follows. It is for dynamically inserting menus via HTML files on our large website, and it works fine. Just can't figure out how to hide certain menus on small screens. I have not been able to find a solution on W3 or anywhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-left-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
      if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
      /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
      elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-left-html");
      includeHTML();
    }
  }      
  xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
  xhttp.send();
  /*exit the function:*/
  return;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<body>

<div w3-include-left-html="borders/border-left.html"></div> 

<script>
includeHTML();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is something like `w3-include-left-html` doing in there anyway? This should at least be prefixed with `data-` to become a proper custom attribute.

Comment: "w3-include-left-html" comes from W3 here:  http://w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp This enables custom menus to be inserted dynamically (server side) from single HTML files to thousands of pages on a website. That is why we use it, and it works well. However, stopping certain menus on small screens to make site mobile friendly has proven to be very difficult. No CSS or Scripts tried so far have worked. This is the site: https://www.aypsite.org  Top, left, right and bottom menus are inserted with the above code. Left and right are the ones I would like to turn off for mobile. Thanks!

Comment: With a little zooming the site is actually not bad on small screens, but it won't pass Google's mobile test with the side menus: https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly Or if the site is resized with --meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"--  body text ends up being two words wide. Manually turning off the side menus works. How to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to use the 'class' selector with div.borders.... your div doesn't have a class attribute

you should instead use:

```
div[w3-include-left-html='borders/border-left.html']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
[w3-include-left-html="borders/border-left.html"] {
display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, neither one of those worked. Not sure why. Still getting the HTML menu files on the mobile phone screen. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The menu file can be removed from the site by removing the URL in the div code, so it is only a matter of hiding the div with the URL in it, which is not happening with anything we have tried so far.

Comment: Could it be that the css action is not working because <div w3-include-left-html="borders/border-left.html"></div> is being called up from within the script shown at the end of my inquiry above? If that is the case, do we have to be stopping the script for small screens? And how do we do that? Thanks again!

Comment: @Yogani If we take a look at your Javascript, then it seems that you are suffering due to the fact that you remove the attribute in the line of elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-left-html");

Comment: "...it seems that you are suffering due to the fact that you remove the attribute in the line of elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-left-html")" Not a programmer here and not sure what this means. The script comes from W3schools (link above) and works. The problem is stopping it for small screens. Not the end of the world, but frustrating that nothing works so far. Thanks!